# How to properly handle req.files in node post request using multer and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, multipartform-data, multer

I am using `multer` and have one file in `req.files`, where `req.files` comes from using the following [middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) version in my endpoint:

`..., upload.array('file', 1)...`

I have defined a `multer` file interface as follows:

```
interface multerFile {
    buffer: Buffer, 
    encoding: string, 
    fieldname: string, 
    mimetype: string, 
    originalname: string, 
    size: number;
};
```

Then I think I can create an array of multer like files, and assign `req.files` to it as follows:

```
let files: multerFile[] = [];
files = req.files;
```

I then want to push the one file I have into an array of attachments:

```
attachments.push({
    "type": files[0].mimetype,
    "name": files[0].originalname,
    "content": files[0].buffer
})
```

However, this is not working because I get this error:

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type '{ [fieldname: string]: File[]; } | File[]'.
```

I also installed the `multer` types and thought I could do the following:

```
    const request: Express.Request = req;
    const files: Express.Multer.File[] = request.files;
```

However, this still gives me an error.

```
error TS2322: Type 'File[] | { [fieldname: string]: File[]; }' is not assignable to type 'File[]'.
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I am facing the same issue in TS. Did you find a solution??

Answer (score 16):

you need to fix types . follow this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

if you are using

```
upload.array('photos', 12)
```

try this code in your handler

```
const files= req.files as Express.Multer.File[];
const myFirstfile=files[0];
```

but if you are using

```
upload.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 }])
```

try this one

```
const files= req.files as  {[fieldname: string]: Express.Multer.File[]};
const myFirstAvatarFile=files['avatar'][0];
```

Answer (score 3):

I Fixed This Using Below Code :

```
req.body.thumbnails = req.files
const product = req.body

await new ProductModel().createProduct(product)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks like it arises because `req.files` is not what you think it is.

Looking at the [multer documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), it appears that the type of `req.files` will vary depending on how you set up the multer middleware.

The basic usage section of the documentation shows three different possibilities:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})

app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})

var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }])
app.post('/cool-profile', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is an object (String -> Array) where fieldname is the key, and the value is array of files
  //
  // e.g.
  //  req.files['avatar'][0] -> File
  //  req.files['gallery'] -> Array
  //
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})
```

You haven't shown us which form of the multer middleware you are using, but the error you're getting suggests that you're using the third option instead of the second.

Comment: Thanks, so this is using the `upload.array('file', `)` version, so I expect an array with one file, and I can see it is there. I am just having TS related issues. If I change the endpoint to use `upload.single('file')`, I can access all the fields without issue, so it's something with the array version and typescript.